# Populating new remote branches in intellij - Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My team has a project added in git(Bitbucket). Intellij has an awesome integration with git. However, a new branch is created for the project by someone else remotely and pushed to the main(bitbucket) repository. This branch doesn't automatically get populated in the 'Git Branches' dialog (in the bottom right) of my intellij. I have checked through **git bash CLI** using the command `git ls-remote origin` and the new branch (**added and pushed by someone else**) indeed does exist. Is there a way to sync intellij with the bitbucket repo and checkout the new branch as local, without having to clone the project all over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, when creating a [new branch in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-a-new-branch.html?origin=old_help), specify its origin:

```
origin/<remoteBanchName>
```

> ### To check out a new local branch from a remote branch
>
> - Invoke the Branches menu as described in Accessing Git Branches Popup Menu.
> - Select a branch in the pop-up list that shows all available local and remote branches, and choose Checkout as new local branch from the submenu.
> - Specify the name of the new branch in the Checkout new branch from `<branch name>` dialog that opens.
>
> The branch with the specified name will be checked out and put under version control.

[A fetch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/fetching-changes-from-a-remote-git-repository.html?origin=old_help) might be needed first to be sure to see the new remote branch.

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Creating a new branch in intellij would create a local branch and it will need to be pushed to remote. What I want is to checkout a new remote branch which has been created by someone else from my team. Since this branch was made by my teammate and pushed to the main(remote) repo after I had cloned the project, it doesn't appear in the branch name dialog. I need a way to get this remote branch in the branchnames dialog so that I can checkout the same, without having to clone the whole project all over again.

Comment: @AnkitKhettry Creatnig a local branch does not mean you will push it. It will mean it will appear in the branch name dialog once created. And it will allow you to detect when the remote branch has new commits that you haven't yet pull to your local branch.

Comment: @AnkitKhettry And you don't need to "clone the whole project again" for that.

Comment: I understand that. The branch in question has already been created in my teammate's local system and then pushed to the repo.

Comment: I guess my question isn't very clear. Editing the post accordingly

Comment: @AnkitKhettry Great: Fetch in your current local clone of that same repo, then create your local branch based on the remote branch and you are done.

Comment: @AnkitKhettry Your question is clear: if you already have a clone of that repo locally, my answer will allow you to make sure that branch will appear in the branch name dialog. Again, without cloning.

Comment: I am still curious why fetch could do it and a pull couldnt. 'Pull' technically is 'fetch' followed by 'merge' as per my understanding.

Comment: @AnkitKhettry It depends on how IntelliJ has implemented its pull: you can fetch just one branch. A default fetch fetches *all* branches.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Update Project` Action on IntelliJ IDEA ( Ctrl + T  on windows) to pull changes from remote (Bitbucket).

**BEFORE**

[image]

**Branch name `demo` is created from Bitbucket Website. Then run the `Update Project` Action**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

You can see the demo branch. If you want to use it you can `checkout` the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Go to in Intellj IDE Menu option :  VCS -> Git -> Fetch its fetches all the newly created  branches.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a pull and checkout of a branch with the same name. It should setup remote tracking automatically and you are done.

Comment: I did a pull, followed by 'Checkout Tag or Revision' of the branch name, but no luck. Says 'Couldn't checkout <branchname>' Am I missing something here??